# Fortran Modules and Global Variables

Tags: variables, module, fortran, global

I'm trying to create a data structure accessible globally to the main program and all subroutines. The data structure is built from reading some .dat files.

This kind of global accessibility seems appropriate for a module. So far my module solution includes: 1) define the data type globally; 2) include (contain) a bunch of subroutines in the module to open/read the .dat files; and 3) construct the data type from the .dat files.

Ideally, I would like to construct this data structure ONCE within the module, and then have this single data structure globally accessible. I do NOT want to open/read the .dat files every time I call the module procedures.

For example. Is there a way to declare the data structure as a global variable from the main program, and then call the module procedures to build the data structure once?

@Ross. Source code:

```
module DataTypeModule

  implicit none

  type :: DatCube
      integer :: NGrid(4)
      double precision, allocatable :: tgrid(:)
  end type DatCube

  contains

  subroutine DataArraySizes(NGrd)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(out) :: NGrd(4)
    open(unit=15, file='./Data/DataHeader.txt', status='old')
    read(15,*) NGrd(1)
    read(15,*) NGrd(2)
    read(15,*) NGrd(3)
    read(15,*) NGrd(4)
    close(15)
  end subroutine DataArraySizes

  subroutine DataTGrd(NGrd,tgrd)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: NGrd(4)
    double precision, intent(out) :: tgrd(NGrd(1))
    open(unit=16, file='./Data/tgrid.dat', status='old')
    read(16,*) tgrd
    close(16)
  end subroutine DataTGrd

  subroutine ConstructDataCube(DataCube)
    implicit none
    type(DatCube), Intent(out) :: DataCube

    integer, allocatable :: NGrd(:)
    double precision, allocatable :: tgrd(:)

    allocate( NGrd(4) )
    call DataArraySizes(NGrd)
    DataCube%NGrid = NGrd

    allocate( tgrd(NGrd(1)),DataCube%tgrid(NGrd(1)) )
    call DataTGrd(NGrd,tgrd)
    DataCube%tgrid = tgrd

    deallocate( NGrd,tgrd )

    return
  end

end module DataTypeModule

program main
  use DatatypeModule
  implicit none
  double precision :: arg1,out1(4)
  type(DatCube) :: DataCube

  call ConstructDataCube(DataCube)

  call subrtn1(arg1,out1)

  stop
end


subroutine subrtn1(arg1,out1)
  use DataTypeModule
  implicit none
  double precision, Intent(in)  :: arg1
  double precision, Intent(out) :: out1(4)
  type(DatCube) :: DataCube

  out1 = DataCube%NGrid

  return
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the source of your confusion. Why not call `read_data` once at the start of your program, and `use` the variables from everywhere?

Comment: @Ross. Each time I call the module procedures (from the main program or various subroutines), it open/reads the .dat files and constructs the data structure. That's a huge time sink. 

I would like to call the module procedure (construct the data structure) once and set this data structure as a global variable accessible to the main program and all subroutines. 

I do not want to pass this data structure as an argument to every subroutine, as I have many nested procedures.

Comment: Well, this is a different version of the source posted before, but it looks smaller so that's good.

Comment: @Ross. The point here is: I want to construct a globally accessible data structure from .dat files. I do not want to pass that data structure as an argument to the (nested) subroutine procedures called from the main program. And I do not want to read the .dat files every time I call the module subroutine.

Comment: I have read and understood your question. Please read and try to understand the answer.

Comment: @Ross. I think that I am not being clear about my question. I do not want to pass 'DataCube' as arguments to routines. In your example, your 'call read_data' within the main program reads 'x,i'; that's fine. However, it seems to me, if you 'call read_data' in a subroutine procedure within the main program, then the module will open/read 'x,i' again in the procedure. I want to avoid the multiple open/read executions in every nested subroutine of my main program; as these become a massive time sink.

Comment: Just have a module procedure called `INIT` which reads and stores the data for recall later.  `READ_DATA` should not be public, but should only be called by `INIT`.  Create a module procedure called `GET_DATA` that returns the bits asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Data that is read once and accessed many times is very common. Here's a simple example of how that can work. The module `my_data` contains both the data to be stored `x,i` and the subroutine to read that data from disk `read_data`. Reading should be called once, and the data may be accessed multiple times from both the main program and subroutines. In the source file `main.f90`:

```
module my_data
   implicit none

   real :: x
   integer :: i

contains
subroutine read_data
   integer :: fid

   open(newunit=fid,file='config.txt',action='read',position='rewind')

   read(fid,*) x
   read(fid,*) i

   close(fid)
end subroutine read_data
end module my_data

module routines
   implicit none

contains
subroutine mysub
   use my_data, only : x, i

   ! -- Use data again
   write(*,*) 'x and i in subroutine are: ', x, i

end subroutine mysub
end module routines

program main
   use my_data, only : read_data, x, i
   use routines, only : mysub
   implicit none

   ! -- Initialize
   call read_data

   ! -- Use data
   write(*,*) 'x and i in main are: ', x, i

   ! -- Use data in subroutine
   call mysub

end program main
```

The file `config.txt` contains the data to be read.

```
mach5% more config.txt
1.23
5
mach5% ifort main.f90 && ./a.out
 x and i in main are:    1.230000               5
 x and i in subroutine are:    1.230000               5
```

Edit: A critical part of what's happening here is that `x` and `i` are *stored* in a place accessible by both the reading module and the main program. In this simple example I chose to store it in `my_data`, but it could conceivably be elsewhere. The sample code you posted, which has since been deleted (please edit it into your question), **never stores the data you have read**. Storing the data after reading it once is essential.

Edit 2: In your edited source, you read the data into the variable `DataCube` which is declared in the main program. Then, you attempt to access the data in the variable `DataCube` which is declared in the subroutine `subrtn1`. **These are not the same variable.** You must declare it once, and access it from multiple places. The best way to do this is by containing it in a module, as I show in my example. However, you can also pass it as arguments to routines, but this becomes cumbersome.

Comment: In your example, can (nested) subroutines called from the main program access the data x,i without passing the x and i as arguments?

Comment: @jkedmond Only if they have access to the appropriate module.

Comment: @VladimirF. What you're saying is that, I do not have to pass x and i as arguments as long as I add the declaration "use my_data, only : read_data, x, i" in the particular subroutine?

Comment: In the subroutine or in the module which contains the subroutine or even higher in the cascade of modules. The `only` part is optional.

Comment: @VladimirF. But then I am back to the same problem ... Each time I call the module procedures (from the main program or various subroutines), it open/reads the .dat files and constructs the data structure. That's a huge time sink. I would like to call the module procedure (construct the data structure) once and set this data structure as a global variable accessible to the main program and all subroutines. I do not want to pass this data structure as an argument to every subroutine, as I have many nested procedures.

Comment: Why would you call the reading??? You don't have to. They have nothing to do with access to `x` and `i`...

Comment: @jkedmond It seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how modules work. If you want further help, I recommend you post some example code.

Comment: Please be patient. I am new to both stack exchange and FORTRAN programming.

Comment: @Ross. I think that I am not being clear about my question. I do not want to pass 'DataCube' as arguments to routines. In your example, your 'call read_data' within the main program reads 'x,i'; that's fine. However, it seems to me, if you 'call read_data' in a subroutine procedure within the main program, then the module will open/read 'x,i' again in the procedure. I want to avoid the multiple open/read executions in every nested subroutine of my main program; as these become a massive time sink.

Answer (score -2):

You can have the module be assumed as PRIVATE or assumed as PUBLIC. I'll show PRIVATE.

```
module DataTypeModule
  implicit none
  PRIVATE                                              !<--

  type :: DatCube_Struct
      integer                                           :: nGrid
      double precision, allocatable, DIMENSION(:)       :: tgrid
  end type DatCube_Struct
  !PUBLIC  DatCube_Struct !(Only needs to be public if you want to use it in separate from DataCube)   
  type(DatCube_Struct), DIMENSION(4)           , PUBLIC :: DataCube   !<--

  double precision, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE, PUBLIC :: tgrd       !<--

  !! PUBLIC DataArraySizes, DataTGrd    !<-- These do not seem to need to be PUBLIC
  PUBLIC ConstructDataCube   !<--

!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  contains
!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
!! subroutine DataArraySizes(NGrd)
subroutine DataArraySizes
implicit none
!!--> integer, intent(out) :: NGrd(4)

open(unit=15, file='./Data/DataHeader.txt', status='old')
read(15,*) NGrd(1)
read(15,*) NGrd(2)
read(15,*) NGrd(3)
read(15,*) NGrd(4)
close(15)

RETURN
end subroutine DataArraySizes

!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
subroutine DataTGrd(i)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: i                      !<--
!! double precision, intent(out) :: tgrd(i)   !-->  (NGrd(1))

open(unit=16, file='./Data/tgrid.dat', status='old')
read(16,*) DataCube(I)%tgrid(:)               !<-- Is this grid(1:4)? or a single like #1 tgrd(1)
close(16)

RETURN
end subroutine DataTGrd

!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
subroutine ConstructDataCube()               !--> (DataCube)
implicit none
!!--> type(DatCube)   , Intent(out) :: DataCube   
!!--> integer         , allocatable :: NGrd(:)
!!--> double precision, allocatable :: tgrd(:)

!!--> allocate( NGrd(4) )
call DataArraySizes()      !!--> (NGrd)

do I = 1, UBOUND(nGrd,1)                              !<--
  DataCube(I)%NGrid = NGrd(I)
ENDDO                                                 !<--

AlloTGrd: do I = 1, UBOUND(nGrd,1)                              !<--
  allocate( tgrd(I ,DataCube(I)%tgrid(NGrd(I)) )
  call DataTGrd(I)
  !!-->  DataCube(I)%tgrid = tgrd(I,:)
ENDDO AlloTGrd

!!deallocate( NGrd,tgrd )

RETURN
END subroutine ConstructDataCube

!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
end module DataTypeModule
!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

PROGRAM main
USE DatatypeModule
implicit none
double precision, PARAMETER    :: arg1 = 1.0D0
double precision, DIMENSION(4) :: out1
!!--> type(DatCube) :: DataCube

call ConstructDataCube(DataCube)

call subrtn1(arg1,out1)

!Why stop ?  stop
end PROGRAM main

!%%%%%%%%%%
subroutine subrtn1(arg1,out1)
use DataTypeModule
implicit none
double precision              , Intent(in   ) :: arg1
double precision, DIMENSION(4), Intent(  out) :: out1
!!--> type(DatCube) :: DataCube

out1 = DataCube(Arg1)%NGrid   !!<-- ??

return
end subroutine subrtn1
```

This "answer" is more to give you ideas rather than being an authoritative compiled "Answer". As the data looked like they were intended to be shared, I put them into the MODULE marked as PUBLIC.